# are these binary relations?

Tags: relations

I have found the following examples of Binary Relations, but I am not pretty sure is the conclusion the author arrived is correct.

X is a number of people

x N y, implies that x lives next to y; for what I see this does not hold the transitive property, so it is not a binary relation, but the author says so? am I wrong?

x S y, x is a sister of y; this example does not hold the symmetric property, but I found the author says it is a binary one, is that right?

thanks

Comment: Do you mean an *equivalence* relation?

Comment: no, I was thinking that a binary relation should hold all the properties, but I found there were some that neglect the others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Binary relations on X are just sets N$\subseteq$X$^2$. They don't have to be transitive.